# Why is content-length header not sent over HTTP/3?

Tags: http, http-headers, http3

While investigating (in Chromium and Firefox devtools) some resources sent over `HTTP/3`, I noticed that the `content-length` header is never sent.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Content-Length` header is not sent because HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 framing are based on the `END_STREAM` flag.

The term "framing" here denotes "how request/response bytes are delimited to indicate the begin and the end of a request/response".

HTTP/1.1, being a textual protocol, needs the `Content-Length` header to indicate the end of the request/response content.

HTTP/2/3, being binary protocols with frames, can just encode this information in the last frame for that request/response.
It is a `HEADERS` or `DATA` frame having the `END_STREAM` flag set to `true` that determines if there is request/response content, and if so, what frame carries the last content bytes.

In summary, the `Content-Length` header is not necessary in HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 because they have a different framing than HTTP/1.1.

Proxies that convert from HTTP/2/3 to HTTP/1.1 synthesize the `Content-Length` header, so that applications based on HTTP/1.1 can look it up, if necessary.
See also: [How http2/http1.1 proxy handle the Transfer-Encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486086/how-http2-http1-1-proxy-handle-the-transfer-encoding/29487781#29487781)